# What is %% for in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand the following Python quine:

```
s = 's = %r\nprint(s%%s)'
print(s%s)
```

In particular, I'm having trouble finding any info about that %% part.
Anyone know what that does exactly, in this context?

Postscript: Sorry for the silly question - it's just an escape character.
My google search was focused on %%, which didn't lead me in the right direction. Thanks to those who took the time to respond!   :)

Comment: Did you try Google? The first few hits for [`Python string percent sign`](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+string+percent+sign) answer your question.

Comment: not a dupe, one looking for an explanation of `%%` doesn't know to look for escaping percents.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`%%` means a percent symbol after using the `%` operator on your string.

`%` is a special symbol for substitutions, so when you put

```
'Hi %s'%name
```

you are substituting a variable into the string at the point where `%s` occurs.
There are lots of other `%` codes for different uses.
But to just get a percent symbol after substitution, you put `%%`.