# Python output formats

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

Hi there I've had a search output formats and formats had no luck. I couldn't find right documentation for it and I really want to learn how this code works if somebody could enlighten me please?

```
    print ("Survived: %i (%.1f%%)"%(len(survived), float(len(survived))/len(train)*100.0))
print ("Not Survived: %i (%.1f%%)"%(len(not_survived), float(len(not_survived))/len(train)*100.0))
print ("Total: %i"%len(train))
```

My questions is inside the code % symbols %i %.1f%% (I believe one decimal) I just really struggle understanding this code how it works (%%%) wise. if somebody could break down for me.

Output is:

```
Survived: 342 (38.4%)
Not Survived: 549 (61.6%)
Total: 891
```

Thank you.

Comment: `%i` is an integer. `%.1f` is a float with 1 decimal place. `%%` is a percent sign. https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Comment: What is %% for in Python? [duplicate]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901852/what-is-for-in-python

Comment: Google "python string percent"

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply John, I've had a look on internet I couldn't find doc. for it. is this belongs to python 2.7?

Answer (score 1):

Python supports different ways of formatting strings. Unfortunately, they are not all in the same place in the documentation. So, I guess it makes sense to put them all in one SO answer :)

What you have in the question is `printf`-style formatting using the modulo (`%`) operator. For the specification of that see [`printf`-style String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting).

Example:

```
x = 9
print('value of x is %d' % x)
```

For formatting using the `format` function, see [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Example:

```
x = 9
print('value of x is {x}'.format(x=x))
```

The same syntax is used as basis for f-strings. See [PEP-0498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

Example:

```
x = 9
print(f'value of x is {x}')
```

There are also template strings, see [Template strings specification](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings).
Example:

```
x = 9
print(string.Template('value of x is $x').substitute(x=x))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate your valuable time. It made things more clear for me.