# What does "%%" mean in Python

Tags: python, operators

What does **%%** do in python?

I know **%** means modulo; but **%%** seems different.

**%%** seems to be a prefix to variables, whenever used.

Comment: Just `%%` will give you: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: It is used in IPython to denote magic methods: `%%timeit`

Comment: I think this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901852/what-is-for-in-python) will help.